# If p>2 is prime and r is primitive root mod p then r^((p-1)/2) == -1 (mod p)

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

If p>2 is prime and r is primitive root mod p then r^((p-1)/2) == -1 (mod p)

Could you help me this statement is true or false ?

I do it by fermat little theorem and I find it equal + - 1(mod p) I am not sure here

Comment: You are right so far.  If $r$ is $1 \pmod p$, is it a primitive root?